# Plotly: How to plot a cumulative "steps" histogram?

Tags: python, histogram, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a cumulative histogram using Plotly in python, but make it look like "steps", i.e. bars with no color and only the top line is displayed. Something like this:

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of the following matplotlib code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(x, cumulative=True, histtype='step')
```

So far, the best I've been able to do is:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
h = go.Histogram(x=x,
                         cumulative=dict(enabled=True),
                         marker=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                                     line=dict(color="red", width=1)))
iplot([h])
```

Which results in something like:
[image]

So what's the trick?

Comment: Did my suggestion solve your problems?

Comment: Well, it definitely works, so thanks for that. However, I find this a bit odd that such a simple request requires so much code, so I just used matplotlib. In general, I find plotly not flexible enough. Anyway, you did answer my question, and since there seems to be no better solutions, I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: Appreciate it! You can always un-accept if a better solution pops up though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to handle the binning and accumulation *before* you plot the data, you can use a `go.Scatter` object with the shape property of the line set to `'hvh'`.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:** Setup for a Jupyter Notebook

```
#imports
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# qtconsole for debugging
#%qtconsole -- style vim

# Notebook settings
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Some sample data
x = np.random.normal(50, 5, 500)
binned = np.histogram(x, bins=25, density=True)
plot_y = np.cumsum(binned[0])

# Line
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=binned[1],
    y=plot_y,
    mode='lines',
    name="X",
    hoverinfo='all',
    line=dict(color = 'rgb(1255, 0, 0)', shape='hvh'
    )
)

data = [trace1]

# Layout
layout = dict(title = 'Binned data from normal distribution',
    legend=dict(
        y=0.5,
        traceorder='reversed',
        font=dict(
            size=16
        )
    )
)

# Make figure
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

# Plot
iplot(fig, filename='line-shapes')
```

I hope this is something you can use!

Don't hesitate to let me know if not.

**Some details:**

The data sample is made using `np.random.normal()`. `x` is a sampled normal distribution  with mean = 50, sigma = 5 and 500 observations. `x` is then put in 50 bins using `np.histogram()` which returns two arrays. These are used as data source for the plot.

**Possible alternative approaches:**

I also tried using your snippet with some random sample data and include `shape='hvh'` in your `line=dict(color="red", width=1)`. That did not seem to work though. I also considered modifying the layout of your `go.Histogram()` so that only the top line of the bars were plotted, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: # Make figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Plot
fig.show()

Comment: The only problem with this approach is the fixed number of bins. How about you do the stats in matplotlib and the plotting in plotly? You can use matplotlib.pyplot.hist https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html to generate the bin values and bin edges (n and bins respectively), then plug these into the plotly scatter plot.

Comment: @ahmedhosny Sounds great! Please do share a complete example!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution works but may be limiting as the bins are all of equal width. One approach is to use matplotlib to calculate stats, then plot with plotly:

```
# sample data
# I am not using a normal distribution on purpose so that the effect of varying bin widths is apparent.
x = np.random.rand(100)

# use matplotlib to get "n" and "bins"
# n_bins will affect the resolution of the cumilative histogram but not dictate the bin widths.
n_bins = 100
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, n_bins, density=True, histtype='step', cumulative=-1)

# use plotly (v3) to plot
data = []
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=bins,
    y=n,
    mode='lines',
    name= "test",
    line=dict(
        shape='hvh'
    )
)

data.append(trace)
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
iplot(fig)
```

The result should look something like this: 
[image]

Comment: That is a very interesting approach that reveals a few things I'be been wondering about for quite some time!