# Plotly: How to make a 3D stacked histogram?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have several histograms that I succeded to plot using [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/) like this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=np.array(data[key]), name=self.labels[i]))
```

I would like to create something like [this 3D stacked histogram](https://plot.ly/~yksuh/1/#/) but with the difference that each 2D histogram inside is a true histogram and not just a hardcoded line (my data is of the form `[0.5 0.4 0.5 0.7 0.4]` so using Histogram directly is very convenient)

Note that what I am asking is not similar to [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) and therefore also not the same as [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-create-a-3d-histogram-with-plotly/8607). In the matplotlib example, the data is presented directly in a 2D array so the histogram is the 3rd dimension. In my case, I wanted to feed a function with many already computed histograms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet below takes care of both binning and formatting of the figure so that it appears as a stacked 3D chart using multiple traces of `go.Scatter3D` and `np.Histogram`.
The input is a dataframe with random numbers using `np.random.normal(50, 5, size=(300, 4))`
We can talk more about the other details if this is something you can use:

**Plot 1:** Angle 1

[image]

**Plot 2:** Angle 2

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

# data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(50, 5, size=(300, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# plotly setup
fig=go.Figure()

# data binning and traces
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    a0=np.histogram(df[col], bins=10, density=False)[0].tolist()
    a0=np.repeat(a0,2).tolist()
    a0.insert(0,0)
    a0.pop()
    a1=np.histogram(df[col], bins=10, density=False)[1].tolist()
    a1=np.repeat(a1,2)
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter3d(x=[i]*len(a0), y=a1, z=a0,
                                mode='lines',
                                name=col
                               )
                  )
fig.show()
```

Comment: This looks very nice! I will adapt it to my code this afternoon and mark it as a solution if it works indeed. Thank you!

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina Happy to help! I know the `a0=np.repeat(a0,2).tolist()` and `a0.pop()` might seem a little strange. But it's only there to create a necessary data structure to remedy the fact that `go.Scatter3D`, unlike `go.Scatter`, does ***not*** have a `line_shape` method that can be set to `'hvh'`. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220935/plotly-how-to-plot-a-cumulative-steps-histogram/55237514#55237514) how that could otherwise have been used to build the same chart as in your [first link](https://plot.ly/~yksuh/1/#/)

Comment: Nice! Worked as charm. However, I tried to make it prettier using `surfaceaxis=0` as a parameter of `go.Scatter3d` but got something horrible. Do you know if it is possible to make it work? Maybe as it is a different question I should do a new question...

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina Please do post that as a new question. I won't have the chance to look at it before next week. So I'm sure someone else will pick ut up before me. If not I'll take a look first chance.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487237/5931672) the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use `go.Histogram` in a 3D space so you should use an alternative way. I used `go.Scatter3d` and I wanted to use the option to fill line [doc](https://plot.ly/python/v3/3d-filled-line-plots/) but there is an evident bug [see](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1206)

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# random mat
m = 6
n = 5
mat = np.random.uniform(size=(m,n)).round(1)

# we want to have the number repeated
mat = mat.repeat(2).reshape(m, n*2)

# and finally plot

x = np.arange(2*n)
y = np.ones(2*n)
fig = go.Figure()
for i in range(m):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x,
                               y=y*i,
                               z=mat[i,:],
                               mode="lines",
                               # surfaceaxis=1 # bug
                               )
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487237/5931672) the solution for the fill surface.

Comment: @Augustin nice. You or empet could actually think to make a PR